# jQuery hasClass() - check for more than one class

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

With:

```javascript
if(element.hasClass("class"))
```

I can check for one class, but is there an easy way to check whether "element" has any of many classes?

I am using:

```javascript
if(element.hasClass("class") || element.hasClass("class") ... )
```

Which isn't too bad, but I am thinking of something like:

```javascript
if(element.hasClass("class", "class2")
```

Which unfortunately doesn't work.

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

How about:

```
element.is('.class1, .class2')
```

Comment: No, because that would look for elements that have both classes. I think Marcel is looking for elements with one or more of a number of classes.

Comment: Just now noticed that I have 4 id="hello" elements there. Fixed version in order to make validators happy: http://jsbin.com/uqoku/2/edit

Comment: @Matchu I was having the same issue with `.hasClass()` but your solution seems to have done the trick, thanks

Comment: This did not work for me, but `$('element').is('.class1.class2')` did

Comment: @iamchriswick: That's slightly different than what OP was asking for. `.class1.class2` will match elements that have _both_ classes, but they were looking for elements that match _either_ class.

Comment: What if I have to write a statement like that:

if (!$('body').hasClass('page-template-default-template') || !$('body').hasClass('single-programs'))

With is?

Comment: @GilesVanGruisen  ...    The comma acts as an OR condition.  just as a CSS selector would.      `".foo.bar"`   would   require both "foo" and "bar" classes

Answer (score 327):

```
element.is('.class1, .class2')
```

works, but it's **35% slower** than

```
element.hasClass('class1') || element.hasClass('class2')
```

[image: JSperf chart showing .hasClass() is faster than .is()]

See also [this jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/awkxd63hj2/1) test.

Comment: 19% slower, big deal. Programmers are more expensive.

Comment: @DamianNowak if those programmers aren't willing to write what amounts to a trivial amount of more code they probably aren't very expensive ones.

Comment: The faster one is probably more readable too, even though it's longer.

Comment: ... um, but I just ran this in jsperf for Chrome 21.0.1180 and the is() method is now about 20% faster. But the hasClass() seems more readable.

Comment: @Akkuma I can't imagine situation where hasClass(..) will run more than few times per second. But I can imagine how ugly it will become when checking 10 classes with hasClass-es, compared to: elem.is('.a, .b, .c, .d, .e, .f, .g, .h, .i, .j').

Comment: @psychobrm: If you have to check 10 classes at once, what you really need is to streamline your class names.  There's no reason for such nonsense.  :)

Comment: Recent testing in 2014: Firefox 24.1.1 esr, 'is' 13% slower - IE10, 'is' 20% slower - Chrome 32.0.1700.76, 'hasClass' 10% slower.  If you don't support Chrome officially, I would use 'hasClass' still.

Comment: This should be abstracted away behind jQuery's API - it should split on the string and perform the most performant method. I feel like this  should be an addition to the existing method since you can't have spaces in class names - it's unambiguous!

Comment: Personally cant see the need for performance optimising. 12000 operations per second seems fast enough to me. I'd say use whichever looks nicer to you. Optimise performance when the need arises.

Comment: There is a word for this - it's called "Premature Optimization". Sure, - if you're running this over a table of 1000 rows - it might be very well worth the optimization. For most people - one-off `.is('.probabbly, .okay')`

Comment: @Norris you should not process thousands of rows on front end x) At least not in any mentioned way.

Comment: As of April 2017, `.is` is 10% faster on Chrome 58, but 20% slower on Firefox 53, and a huge 60% slower on Edge 15 - all tests on Windows 10 1703

Answer (score 44):

```
$.fn.extend({
    hasClasses: function (selectors) {
        var self = this;
        for (var i in selectors) {
            if ($(self).hasClass(selectors[i])) 
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

$('#element').hasClasses(['class1', 'class2', 'class3']);
```

This should do it, simple and easy.

Comment: You are missing a var in the for (i in selectors), thus creating a global.

Comment: A bit of a minor point, but the parameter **selectors** should really be named **classes** or **classNames**, since that's what you're passing in, not selectors. Selectors would have a dot in front of them, as in $('#element').hasClasses(['.class1', '.class2', '.class3']);

Answer (score 14):

[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is another option

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
>   pass the function's test.

```
$(selector).filter('.class1, .class2'); //Filter elements: class1 OR class2

$(selector).filter('.class1.class2'); // Filter elements: class1 AND class2
```

Comment: be sure to tack on `.length === 0` if you expecting a `bool` val.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
if (element.hasClass("class1 class2")
```

Comment: This does not work if you are looking at an OR condition.

Answer (score 4):

here's an answer that does follow the syntax of

```
$(element).hasAnyOfClasses("class1","class2","class3")
```

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.hasAnyOfClasses = function(){
        for(var i= 0, il=arguments.length; i<il; i++){
            if($self.hasClass(arguments[i])) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

it's not the fastest, but its unambiguous and the solution i prefer.
bench: http://jsperf.com/hasclasstest/10

Comment: `Error: $self is not defined`

Comment: @bagofmilk My reply has been edited by others since I wrote it 6 years ago. Since I've not used jQuery in years, I don't know exactly what was intended with the edit but originally I had `var $self = $(this);` just before the for-loop

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
if ($('.class.class2.class3').length) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: You don't need the  `> 0`. If the length is non-zero it will return true.

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery**

```
if( ['class', 'class2'].some(c => [...element[0].classList].includes(c)) )
```

**Vanilla JS**

```
if( ['class', 'class2'].some(c => [...element.classList].includes(c)) )
```

Comment: Your jQuery isn't jQuery, it's identical to the vanilla JS, except you're targetting element[0] instead of just element..?

Answer (score 1):

What about this,

```
$.fn.extend({
     hasClasses: function( selector ) {
        var classNamesRegex = new RegExp("( " + selector.replace(/ +/g,"").replace(/,/g, " | ") + " )"),
            rclass = /[\n\t\r]/g,
            i = 0,
            l = this.length;
        for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
            if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 && classNamesRegex.test((" " + this[i].className + " ").replace(rclass, " "))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Easy to use,

```
if ( $("selector").hasClasses("class1, class2, class3") ) {
  //Yes It does
}
```

And It seems to be faster,
http://jsperf.com/hasclasstest/7

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old, but hear me out on this one.

```js
$.fn.extend({
  hasClasses: function (selectors) {
      // Setup
      const _id = $(this).attr('id'); // Preserve existing id
      const uuid = generateUUID();    // Create new id for query
      $(this).attr('id', uuid);       // Apply new id to element
     
      // Query to find if element has any of the classes
      const res = selectors.some(cls => !!$(`${uuid}.${cls}`).length);
      
      // Rollback on id 
      if (!_id) $(this).removeAttr("id"); // No Id to begin with
      else $(this).attr('id', _id);       // Preserve old id
      
      // Done
      return res;
    }
})
```

Instead of trying to find a match between one of the classes in `selectors` and one of the element's classes we simply apply a temporary `id` (uuid) to the element and query to find if there exists some element with that temporary `id` and any of the classes listed in `selectors`.

This inspired by [Kalel Wade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030449/kalel-wade)'s and [Simon Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886539/simon-arnold)'s solution but with a minor improvement to performance (benchmarked on [jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/4okpiu6xl1/1)).

##### *Note*

*JSBENCH doesn't allow saving over a limit of a certain amount of characters or words. I had some trouble with the async fetching of random words, so you can get random words manually and use the bench that way.*

## EDIT:

I just noticed that for my implementation of this I am relying on the `id` with async calls. I might cause an issue if I need to query the element by id the same time that `hasClasses` changes the `id`.

To circumvent this we can just add a unique `uuid` attribute (literally just the `uuid`).

Here is the correction:

```js
$.fn.extend({
  hasClasses: function (selectors) {
    // Setup
    const uuid = generateUUID(); // Create new uuid to query later
    $(this).attr(uuid, "");      // Apply uuid to element for query

    // Query to find if element has any of the classes
    const res = selectors.some(cls => !!$(`[${uuid}].${cls}`).length);

    // Remove the uuid attribute
    $(this).removeAttr(uuid);

    // Done
    return res;
  }
})
```

We could still use an the elements' `id` if it has one instead of adding an `attribute`.
I'm not sure if querying `id`s is faster or not. I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460644/in-jquery-is-selecting-by-class-or-id-faster-than-selecting-by-some-other-attri), but by the looks of it there isn't much of a hit with modern browsers. Could still implement using the `id` if it exists instead of an `attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

use default js match() function:

```
if( element.attr('class') !== undefined && element.attr('class').match(/class1|class2|class3|class4|class5/) ) {
  console.log("match");
}
```

to use variables in regexp, use this:

```
var reg = new RegExp(variable, 'g');
$(this).match(reg);
```

by the way, this is the fastest way: http://jsperf.com/hasclass-vs-is-stackoverflow/22

Comment: Like this answer best, although I suspect that looping through the classes and using a string indexOf test might be even faster still...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
if($(selector).filter('.class1, .class2').length){
    // Or logic
}

if($(selector).filter('.class1.class2').length){
    // And logic
}
```

Comment: The and logic has wrong selector '.class1, .class2' instead '.class1.class2'.

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi Thanks for pointing me to the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is uniquely identifiable (by id for example), you might check something like:

```
if($("#id.class, #id.class2").length)
```

If the element is uniquely identifiable among its siblings (for example, it's the only **DIV** element among them), you might check something like:

```
if(element.parent().find(">div.class, >div.class2").length)
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
$('.class1[class~="class2"]').append('something');
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: This is actually a great answer. The above selector syntax grabs all elements with both class1 and class2. Then you can do what you like with it, in this case append. Haven't checked performance compared to other methods but the syntax is nice and succinct.

Comment: @TimWright This is a terrible answer. The normal way to select an element with 2 classes is `$('.class1.class2')` with no need to use an attribute selector for the second class. Also, the question is asking how to select an element by one of any, not all classes.

Answer (score -1):

**Works for me:**

```
 if ( $("element").hasClass( "class1") || $("element").hasClass("class2") ) {

 //do something here

 }
```

Comment: The OP is explicitly trying to avoid the verbosity of your solution.