# jQuery - check if element has all classes from an arrray

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dinamically build array of classes:

```
var classes = new Array();
classes.push('class1');
classes.push('class2');
classes.push('class5');
```

and would like to select with jquery any element, that has all of those classes (but not only those classes), eg:

```
<a class="class1 class2 class5 class10 class18">my element</a>
```

How should I slove that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232604/jquery-check-if-element-has-a-class-from-an-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may get your elements with

```
$('.'+classes.join('.'))
```

In your case, the resulting selector would be `".class1.class2.class5"`.

Note that this assumes there is at least one element in your `classes` array.

Comment: or $('.'+classes.join('.'))

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky Yes, that's more elegant. I'll steal it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this 
color is your array of class names here is piece of code

```
  for ( var i = 0; i < color .length; i++ )
    {
      if ( $(this).hasClass( color[i] ) )
      {       
        break;  
      }
    }
```

also check out this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/