# Check if element contains any of the class from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following elements:

```
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight"></div>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight ten"></div>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight"></div>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight"></div>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight eleven"></div> 
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight nine"></div>
```

And the following JS:

```
var obj = ['nine', 'ten', 'eleven'];
```

How do I check if any of these elements has one of the classes in the array?

Comment: Cartesian Check! Woah! `:P`

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? Do you just want to select all the divs that contains a class in your array?

Comment: If you really mean check then https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/ will be used somewhere

Comment: like that? [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td5n4hu3/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need of loop over each of the element  and each of the class to check it it exists on the element.

You can use `regex` as follow:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kumph75c/5/)

```js
var arr = ['nine', 'ten', 'eleven'];
var classes = '\\b(' + arr.join('|') + ')\\b',
  regex = new RegExp(classes, 'i');


$('div').each(function() {
  var elClasses = ' ' + $(this).attr('class').replace(/\s+/, ' ') + ' ';
  if (regex.test(elClasses)) {
    $(this).addClass('valid');
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  color: red;
}
.valid {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight">Invalid</div>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight ten">Valid Ten</div>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight">Invalid</div>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight">Invalid</div>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight eleven">Valid 11</div>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight nine">Valid 9</div>
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

1. `\b`: Will match the word boundary
2. `|`: Works as *OR* in regex
3. `arr.join('|')`: Will join all the elements of array using `|` to join
4. `()`: Capturing Group. In this case used for matching one of the class

So, `regex` in above case will be

```
/\b(nine|ten|eleven)\b/
```

Comment: One of the best! `:)`

Comment: code bloat for capabilities that already exist in jQuery core

Comment: It matches anything, for instance `tentacles` would be a valid class. Adding boundaries would help, but matching classes, especially multiple classes, with a regex, has it's issues.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for pointing out mistakes. Kindly see **http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kumph75c/4/**. I've also updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check if any of these elements has one of the classes in the
>   array

You'd have to iterate over elements and classes, and check if each element contain any of the classes in the array, something like this

```
var elements = $('div');
var obj      = ['nine', 'ten', 'eleven'];

var hasClass = elements.filter(function(index, elem) {
    return obj.some(function(klass) {
        return elem.classList.contains(klass);
    });
}).length > 0;
```

You could easily make that into a function

```
function hasClass(elements, classes) {
    return elements.filter(function(index, elem) {
        return classes.some(function(klass) {
            return elem.classList.contains(klass);
        });
    }).length > 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ysgjesrc/)

Using `Array.some` and `Element.classList.contains` to avoid uneccessary iteration and slow matching of classnames.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkClasses () {
    var tagsWithClasses = [];
    $.each($("div"), function( index, value ){
         for (i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
              if ($(value).hasClass(obj[i])) {
                    tagsWithClasses.push($(value));
                    continue;
              }
         }
    });

    return tagsWithClasses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function () {
    var found = false;
    var element_classes = $(this)[0].className.split(/\s+/);

    // Loop each class the element has
    for (var i = 0; i < element_classes.length; i++) {
        // Check if each class from the element is within the array of classes we want to match
        if (['nine', 'ten', 'eleven'].indexOf(element_classes[i]) !== -1) {
            // We found a match, break out of the loop
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // check if found or not
    if (found) {
        // Was found
    }
    else {
        // Was not found
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = ['nine', 'ten', 'eleven'];
var divs =[];
$.each(obj,function(key,value){

  var values = value;
  $(div).each(function(){
  var divId = $(this).attr('id');  // Giving some separate id for the div to track it
  var getClass = $(this).attr('class');

  if(getClass.indexOf(values) >= 0) {
    div.push("divId");
  }
 });
});
```

You can loop through the elements and the the result

Answer (score 0):

Question depends on what you are trying to do.

If you are trying to create a collection of those elements you can create a selector from the array:

```
var elemCollection = $(  '.' + obj.join(',.') ).doSomething();
```

Can also be used in `filter()`

```
$existingElementCollection.filter(  '.' + obj.join(',.') ).doSomething();
```

Or can be used in `is()`

```
var filterSelector =  '.' + obj.join(',.');
$someCollection.each(function(){
   if($(this).is( filterSelector ){
     // do somthing for matches
   }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x6pgdjwd/)**</kbd>