# Jquery If class has matching ID then hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do here is check if an element has the same `id` as a `class` in another element if so hide the matching `id`.

So far this is what I have came up with but it doesn't seem to kick.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d65sz4js/)

```js
var theid = $('#me li').attr('id');

if ($('#you li').hasClass( theid )) {
  
  $('#me li#'+theid+'').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="me">
  <li id="num-0">iam 1</li>
  <li id="num-1">ieam 2 &amp; should be hidden</li>
  <li id="num-2">iam 3</li>
  <li id="num-3">iam 4</li>
  <li id="num-4">ieam 5 &amp; should be hidden</li>
  <li id="num-5">iam 6</li>
</ul>

<ul id="you">
  <li class="num-1">iam killer</li>
  <li class="num-4">iam killer</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `;` is not needed after `hasClass()`

Comment: Why should the element with `id="num-1"` be hidden? There's no element with a `num-1` class. Please update your example to make it consistent with the description of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `each()` to loop over all the `li` elements inside the `#you`
2. `hide()` the elements having the `id` same as the `class` of current element in loop.

```js
$('#you li').each(function() {
  $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="me">
  <li id="num-0">iam 1</li>
  <li id="num-1">ieam 2</li>
  <li id="num-2">iam 3 &amp; should be hidden</li>
  <li id="num-3">iam 4</li>
  <li id="num-4">ieam 5 &amp; should be hidden</li>
  <li id="num-5">iam 6</li>
</ul>
<ul id="you">
  <li class="num-2">iam killer</li>
  <li class="num-4">iam killer</li>
</ul>
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/d65sz4js/1/)

Comment: @Pepo_rasta No, this will work for the code OP has provided

Comment: Hi Tushar it rally needs to keep to the if statement

Comment: @DCdaz Why? Anyway, you re checking if the element have `class` and then you're hiding it

Comment: for other reasons it's ok

Comment: Will go with your's Tushar as you have produced the dryest answer and I like it.

Comment: @Pepo_rasta Multiple classes can be tricky, but surely can be done http://stackoverflow.com/a/31386150/2025923 using this way

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `.attr()` method on a jQuery object that contains multiple elements, it just returns the attribute from the first element. You need to loop over each element and check them one at a time.

It is, however, OK for your purposes to use `.hasClass()` on the set of all of the `#you` elements, because `.hasClass()` will return `true` if any of the elements in the set has that class. So:

```
var you = $('#you li');

$('#me li').each(function() {
    if (you.hasClass(this.id))
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Note that I'm keeping a reference to the `$('#you li')` jQuery object in the variable `you` to save selecting those elements again every time in the loop.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d65sz4js/2/

Comment: I like this answer so put it as a plus one thank's nnn

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#you li").each(function(){
        var theid = $(this).attr('class');
        $('#'+theid).hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nkem9o7o/

Comment: What if the simple example html was a bit more complicated and the `#you li` elements had more than one class assigned?

Comment: I said "What if". What I'm getting at is that it's just as easy to code it the other way around and then it would cater for the html shown or for multiple classes.

Comment: I'm giving a solution to the OP's current problem. I don't know what he intends to do in the future. I actually don't even understand why he's doing a check on a `class` instead of other attributes. But he is :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could `filter` the `#me li`'s, returning elements where their `id` exists as a class in `#you li`'s, then just hide them. This would also work for multiple classes:

```
$('#me li').filter(function() {
   return $('#you').has('.' + this.id).length;
}).hide();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/billyonecan/d65sz4js/4/)