# jQuery/Isotope complex AND/OR filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-isotope

I have and isotope instance with elements with many parameters, for example let's say:

```
<element data-a="1 2 3 4 5" data-b="1 2 3 4 5" data-c="1 2 3 4 5"
```

When I want to display an element which is A1, B2 and C3 it's simple filter:

```
.isotope({ filter: '[data-a~=1][data-b~=2][data-c~=3]' });
```

However, i need more complex filters like (A1 or 2 or 3) AND (B1 or 2 or 3 or 4) AND C1

AFAIK there is no way to do "OR" in CSS selectors like:

```
.isotope({ filter: '[data-a~=1 OR 2 OR 3][data-b~=1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4][data-c~=1]' });
```

How to apply such complex filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isotope uses the jQuery selection engine, with the CSS3 selection syntax.

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
.isotope({ filter: '[data-a~=1], [data-a~=2], [data-a~=3]' });
```

This filter selector matches all those elements having an attribute data-a containing value 1, 2, OR 3

Creating the more complex statement your last statement can be done by combining the two methods, the following is an untested "best guess"

```
.isotope({ filter: '[data-a~=1][data-b~=1][data-c~=1], [data-a~=1][data-b~=2][data-c~=1], [data-a~=1][data-b~=3][data-c~=1], [data-a~=1][data-b~=4][data-c~=1], [data-a~=2][data-b~=1][data-c~=1], [data-a~=2][data-b~=2][data-c~=1], [data-a~=2][data-b~=3][data-c~=1], [data-a~=2][data-b~=4][data-c~=1], [data-a~=3][data-b~=1][data-c~=1], [data-a~=3][data-b~=2][data-c~=1], [data-a~=3][data-b~=3][data-c~=1], [data-a~=3][data-b~=4][data-c~=1]' });
```

All I did was "distribute" your "OR"s into the Selector syntax.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - that's working! I have nested iterating loops to generate the filter statement. However it's not very clean and definatelly not efficient solution. I have ~30 categories in A, ~15 categories in B and ~10 in C. So if everything gets selected the query contains about 30 * 15 * 10 = 4500 sections (!!). That's hanging the browser for a while... Selecting half options = the same. Is there more efficient solution?

Case background:
There is a database of 250 elements, displayed in masonry grid with 3 parameters (30 categories, 15 areas and ~10 tags). I need to sort it in frontend.

Comment: There are better ways, but they don't relate to your specific question about how to use OR with isotope's filter selector. If you think my answer directly answers that, can you mark it correct? Thanks!

Comment: First thing I would try is to use classes instead of data selectors. Add classes with very specific information like `row4` and `circularThings` and use the same selecting principles: `.isotope({ filter: '.circularThings.row4' });`. Selecting by data attributes is notoriously slow. See [this other stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533285/jquery-select-by-class-vs-select-by-attribute). There are many other strategies. Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Doesn't Isotope, being a jQuery plugin, use jQuery's selector engine anyway?