# parsing values from initial form into bootbox confirm dialog popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootbox

idI have a form from which I trigger the Bootbox dialog popup window like this:

```
$(function() {
  return $("#buy_order_btn").click(function() {
    return bootbox.dialog({
      title: "Confirm Buy Order",
      message: " // here should come the product name from the initial form"
    });
  });
});
```

Question: How can I display the values from the initial order form within the message part in bootbox?

I was thinking about something like

```
var product = $("input[id='product']").val()
```

but i am not sure. Please advise

Edit:

the initial form looks like this:

```
<form>
<input type=text id=product>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you trying to work with the content of `message` ? In that case, you need to add the whole form into the message. Otherwise, show the whole html ! Where is the input you are trying to work with ?

Comment: @Nico - the data I want to display within bootbox.dialog is in the initial form.

Comment: Don't forget to add `"` between the attribute value : `type="text"` and `id="product"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form is like

```
<form>
  <input name="product" value="productValue"/>
</form>
```

You can access the value of input the way you want i.e. `$('input[name="product"]');`. You absolutely need the attribute `name` to exist on the input otherwise it won't work. Be careful not to mix `'` and `"` in your selector.

If your input have an id or a class

```
<input id="idOfInput" class="classNameOfInput" name="product" value="productValue"/>
```

You can access it with:

```
$('.classNameOfInput').val();
$('#idOfInput').val();
```

It is much faster to select by classname or by id than by attribute so I advice you to use class or id. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533285/jquery-select-by-class-vs-select-by-attribute) for more information about performance.

As you edited the question here is how to acheive what you want :

```
$(function() {
  return $("#buy_order_btn").click(function() {
    return bootbox.dialog({
      title: "Confirm Buy Order",
      message: $('#product').val() // The product code here.
    });
  });
});
```