# What is the naming convention for CSS classes for styling and for events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, naming-conventions

What is a smart way to name CSS classes to be able to distinct between those used for styling and those for JS events?

Looking at a `div` with 4 CSS classes, it would speed things up for me, if I could see if the class is used for only styling or only design, to reduce debugging-time.

I know I can start prefixing all CSS-style classes with `style_`, but is there a better way, that's maybe are a convention too?

Comment: So JavaScript specific and no jQuery?

Comment: What I mean is you tagged javascript but not jQuery. I have a solution but jQuery only.

Comment: I use jQuery too. I would love to hear your solution.

Comment: Cool, Posted :)

Comment: There is a convention called BEM which is useful not only for JS/Style distinction but also for better naming practices. Check it here: http://getbem.com/naming/ hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use "js-" in the begining of all classes used for JS events.

Comment: I like that. It's shorter than my `style_` and I modify the second part (JS) and leave the styling-classes untouched, that's probably also have a stronger intuitive binding.

Comment: We also use that js- notation. Sometimes we also try to use data-attributes for JS-purposes

Comment: do you mean all classes, or just the hook-class? Like if click event reads data from 2 elements and changes another 3 elements, do you create 6 css classes with js- prefix, or 4? or 3? or just 1 (to put on the button)?

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery (don't know js solution) you can use data types and forget about selecting VIA class or ID.

https://jsfiddle.net/tcfhdfth/1/

```
<div data-event="changeBackground"><h1>hello</h1></div>

$("[data-event='changeBackground']").css('background-color', 'red');
```

You don't need to call it data-event. You can call it anything you like. Just not a reserved word.

To create listeners you can do the following.

```
$('body').on('click', "[data-event='changeBackground']", function () {
    $("[data-event='changeBackground']").css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

Performance is much better as explained here [jQuery select by class VS select by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533285/jquery-select-by-class-vs-select-by-attribute)

Comment: So how would you write this? " $('body').on('click', '.deleteGrps', function () { } ". I mean, can you bind, like I do with ("$('body'"), before the element is created in the DOM?

Comment: Meaning deleteGrps is the class you're selecting?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tcfhdfth/2/ In the fiddle's case only a h1 is used so the body wraps around the h1. SOOOOO...click on the h1 xD

Comment: My comment above this one is so stupid. It's late afternoon here and I want to go home. No need to click on 'body' as the listener is on 'h1'...but you knew that already ;)

Comment: Why did you choose this approach, instead of a simple prefix? Is it deliberately to avoid any possible errors for the Style/JS issue and to make it more readable? Or is there more / other reasons? Prefix "js-" is so neat and simple, as long as you remembered it.. :)

Comment: No worries, I only clicked the text anyways. It was just the syntax I was looking for and expecting.

Comment: You can honestly call it what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/tcfhdfth/3/ It is js="" now :). Oh wait you mean instead of using classes. You want JS specific and this way you don't need to worry about selecting styled classes.

Comment: OOOHHHH...Performance is much better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533285/jquery-select-by-class-vs-select-by-attribute

Comment: Oh I have to go with the prefix then if it's x10 times faster. Much appriciation though bro.

Comment: Second answer gave me a different story. Haha