# JQUERY sometimes element is not found if element is specified

Tags: jquery

I have a code.

```
var countRow = $('table#receiving-stock-view tr').length - 1;
var ar = new Array();
for(var iter=0;iter<countRow;iter++){
ar[iter] = $('div.modal table#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter).find('input[name=rspid]').attr('id')
        +","+$('div.modal table#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter).find('input[name=rsqty]').val()
        +","+$('div.modal table#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter).find('input[name=rscost]').val()
        +","+$('div.modal table#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter).find('input[name=rssrp]').val();
        console.log($('table#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter).find('input[name=rsqty]').val());
        console.log(ar[iter]);
}
```

However, during the loop, it only works for the first row, consistently. It fails randomly on the other rows.

HOWEVER,

```
for(var iter=0;iter<countRow;iter++){
ar[iter] = $('#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter).find('input[name=rspid]').attr('id')
        +","+$('#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter).find('input[name=rsqty]').val()
        +","+$('#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter).find('input[name=rscost]').val()
        +","+$('#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter).find('input[name=rssrp]').val();
}
```

If I do not specify which element to find and leave the ids, it reads all the values properly. Any idea why this happens? It is really wierd.

EDIT: I add a new row using ajax. and the whole table is inside a modal class.

```
<table id="receiving-stock-view">

 <thead hidden="true" style="display: table-header-group;">
 <tr>
 <th>Product</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>
 <th>Cost</th>
 <th>SRP</th>
 <th>Sub-Total</th></tr>
 </thead>

  <tbody>
 <tr id="0">
 <td><span><input type="text" value="HeadPhoneszs" name="rspid" id="1"></span></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="1" name="rsqty" id="rsqty_id"></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="1" name="rscost" id="rscost_id"></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="1" name="rssrp" id="rssrp_id"></td></tr>
 <tr id="1"><td><span><input type="text" value="vp" name="rspid" id="13"></span></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="2" name="rsqty" id="rsqty_id"></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="2" name="rscost" id="rscost_id"></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="2" name="rssrp" id="rssrp_id"></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: much better if you can post your HTML code.

Comment: Do you have more than one div with modal as class?

Comment: actually, yes. I add a new row using ajax. And everything happens inside a modal class. How did you know?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you use

   ```
   $('div.modal table#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter)
   ```

the browser first looks for a div that has a `modal` class. As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485619/jquery-sometimes-element-is-not-found-if-element-is-specified#comment28901635_19485619) , you do have more than 1 div with same class. This can make the browser to choose any one div element. So this can fail randomly.

2. When you use

   ```
   $('#receiving-stock-view tr#'+iter)
   ```

the browser tries to match the id `receiving-stock-view` of the table with the DOM element. Since its unique, its able to successfully match the table row every time.

If you are able to use an [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460644/in-jquery-is-selecting-by-class-or-id-faster-than-selecting-by-some-other-attri) to match, then that is the best and most efficient way to match an element in DOM. In such cases, the [pre-selectors](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/) are not needed and they degrade the performance of the web page.