# jQuery click function slow (lagging) on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

So i have this click function that toggles a dropdown-menu, but on Smartphones this is slow and not smooth.

Is there any other way to make this dropdown work with a smooth transition on any mobile device using jQuery?

(I've heard about "vclick" but couldn't find out how to make this work.

```
$j('.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
$j('.dropdown-menu').not(this).children('ul').slideUp("slow");
$j(this).children('ul').slideDown("slow");
});


$j('.dropdown-menu').blur(function() {
$j('.dropdown-inside').hide('slow', function() {
});
});
```

Comment: `vclick` is a custom event only available in JQM framework.

Answer (score 3):

Try the click on Id rather then class. Class is always slow. So suppose if your dropdown has id like 'myDropdown' then do it like

```
$j('#myDropdown').click(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The first part can be simplified to this:

```
$j('.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
    $j('.dropdown-menu').not(this).children('ul').slideToggle(2000);
});
```

Also, try wrapping the hidden content in a `div` and giving it a `width`. When you click on the `div`, it actually pulls it out of position to measure it before quickly replacing it because JQuery doesn't know the dimensions of your hidden `div` until it's displayed. So . This could make the whole animation laggy!

**Another suggestion:**

`ID` is faster than `class`. Part of the reason is that `ID` is supposed to be unique, so the API stops searching after the `ID` is found in the DOM.

If you must use a `class` or `attribute` selector, you can improve performance by specifying the optional context parameter.

**[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6460752/3739658)**

Comment: Thanks! seems to be a bit faster now. Giving the hidden div a width makes the transition even on the desktop version look much better! I'm afraid I need to find another way of coding this, because it is still not the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

**Cause**
*According to [Google](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons) :*
...mobile browsers will wait approximately 300ms from the time that you tap the button to fire the click event. The reason for this is that the browser is waiting to see if you are actually performing a double tap.

**Solution**
 1. Use fastclick.js to get rid of this 300ms lag
https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick
 2. Use application cache to speed up the load 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache