# How faster is using id instead of class for single jQuery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I often use `.class` to select a single html element. However, this is not correct. I've read somewhere that using `#id` is the optimal approach when using jQuery. How much faster is using `#id` instead of `.class` when trying to select a single element?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460644/in-jquery-is-selecting-by-class-or-id-faster-than-selecting-by-some-other-attri

Comment: That's completely browser implementation dependent.

Comment: I would think the performance is negligible but Id is probably faster because once it would find it, it would stop looking. I think its better to just use Id's when you want a single element, classes when you need multiple elements because it makes nicer code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [link](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-speed-tests/98) that taken from [ewwink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458214/ewwink)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21233593/1620210), yes selecting by ID are faster than single class in any common browser.

[image: jsperf]

Comment: This would make sense because instead of looking for every instance like you would with a class you would be looking for for a single element and then stopping.