# how to hide show content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating a work section and in that section i've created a navigation with some image containers

[image]

now when the user click on one of the navigation link . it would show the relative image container linked to that navigation link . for example if i clicks on the branding link it will show me the image container with the class branding. it's just like mix it up plugin but i'm not allowed to use mixitup.

i was trying this : https://jsfiddle.net/to1uuvnb/19/

but it didn't helped

```
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified nav-tabss">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Branding</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Advertise</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Print</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="branding">
        branding
      </div>
      <div class="advertise">
        advertise
      </div>
      <div class="print">
        print
      </div>
```

my js

```
$('.nav-tabss').children('li').click(function(){

 var branding = $(this).text();

 if ( branding === "branding" )
 {
    $('.branding').show();
    $('.adverise').hide();
    $('.print').hide()
 }

});
```

i know my js code is not efficient . if you guys can update the code that would be better and helpful thanks

Comment: What do you mean _you are not allowed_? Is this an assignment?

Comment: You should use **id** attributes instead of **class** here to identify the divs: ```<div id="branding">...``` etc.

see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460644/in-jquery-is-selecting-by-class-or-id-faster-than-selecting-by-some-other-attri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.nav-tabss li a').click(function(){

    var branding = $(this).text();
//alert(branding)
     if ( branding === "Branding" )
     {
        $('.branding').show();
        $('.advertise').hide();
        $('.print').hide()
     }
    if ( branding === "All" )
     {
        $('.branding').show();
        $('.advertise').show();
        $('.print').show()
     }
     if ( branding === "Advertise" )
     {
        $('.branding').hide();
        $('.advertise').show();
        $('.print').hide()
     }
    if ( branding === "Print" )
     {
        $('.branding').hide();
        $('.advertise').hide();
        $('.print').show()
     }


  });
```

use this code

Comment: What if he wants to change the text of the links, this'll break.

Comment: yes exactly, this can also be done if he uses the classes on the anchor tag, and use them accordingly there are many ways to do this thing using parent child concept also

Comment: How is this the accepted answer, its overly complicated code. The OP is using bootstrap he's better off using bootstrap as its intended.

Answer (score 2):

Check you want the same:

```
$('.nav-tabss').children('li').click(function(){

    var branding = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();

     if ( branding === "branding" )
     {
        $('.branding').show();
        $('.advertise').hide();
        $('.print').hide()
     }
    else if( branding === "advertise" )
     {
        $('.branding').hide();
        $('.advertise').show();
        $('.print').hide()
     }
    else if( branding === "print" )
     {
        $('.branding').hide();
        $('.advertise').hide();
        $('.print').show()
     }
    else 
     {
        $('.branding').show();
        $('.advertise').show();
        $('.print').show()
     }

  });
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/to1uuvnb/22/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use data attribute instead of using href or text node, data attribute is flexible.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified nav-tabss">
   <li class="active"> <a data-filter="all" class="trigger" href="#">All</a></li>
   <li> <a data-filter="branding" class="trigger" href="#">Branding</a></li>
   <li> <a data-filter="advertise" class="trigger" href="#">Advertise</a></li>
   <li> <a data-filter="print" class="trigger" href="#">Print</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="branding">branding</div>
<div class="advertise">advertise</div>
<div class="print">print</div>
```

Javascript code use switch statement to show hide divs.

**JS**

```
$('.trigger').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var branding = $(e.target).data('filter');
    console.log(branding);

    switch (branding) {

        case "branding":
            $('.branding').show();
            $('.advertise').hide();
            $('.print').hide();
            break;

        case "advertise":
            $('.advertise').show();
            $('.branding').hide();
            $('.print').hide();

            break;

        case "print":
            $('.advertise').hide();
            $('.branding').hide();
            $('.print').show();
            break;

        case "all":
            $('.advertise').show();
            $('.branding').show();
            $('.print').show();
            break;

        default:
            $('.branding').show();
            $('.advertise').show();
            $('.print').show();

    }
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/to1uuvnb/26/)

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at your html it looks like you're using bootstrap. Why don't you just use [bootstrap's tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#nav-tabss a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="nav-tabss">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#none" data-toggle="tab">All</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#branding" data-toggle="tab">Branding</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#advert" data-toggle="tab">Advertise</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#print" data-toggle="tab">Print</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="none">None</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="branding">Branding</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="advert">Advertise</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="print">Print</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.nav-tabss').on('click','a',function(){

var branding = $(this).text();

 if ( branding === "Branding" )
 {
    $('.branding').show();
    $('.adverise').hide();
    $('.print').hide()
 }
```

});