# jQuery get area to modify by ID then by ID of componet

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all I can not seem to get this to work in jQuery even though I know that it can:

my HTML code:

```
<div class="cd-panel from-right" id="va">
    <header class="cd-panel-header" style="max-width: 600px;">
        <h1 style="margin-top: 5px;" id="panHeading"></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="cd-panel-container" style="max-width: 600px; width: 600px;">
    [more html code here...]
    <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="RequestID" disabled="True" class="form-control input-sm" 
           id="RequestID" style="width: 520px; max-width: 520px;" type="text">
       </div>
    </div>
    [more html code here...]
</div>
<div class="cd-panel from-right" id="VDA">
    <header class="cd-panel-header" style="max-width: 600px;">
        <h1 style="margin-top: 5px;" id="panHeading"></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="cd-panel-container" style="max-width: 600px; width: 600px;">
    [more html code here...]
    <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="RequestID" disabled="True" class="form-control input-sm" 
           id="RequestID" style="width: 520px; max-width: 520px;" type="text">
       </div>
    </div>
    [more html code here...]
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
if (responce["personData1"][0].RequestID != 1) {
   $('#va > #RequestID').val(responce["personData1"][0].RequestID);
}
```

But it never puts the value inside that **RequestID** text box for **VA** even though it **does** have a value for RequestID. If I do this:

```
$('#RequestID').val(responce["personData1"][0].RequestID);
```

Then it has the value inside the text box.

What would I be missing?

Comment: Identifiers in HTML must be unique.

Comment: Sure you can @Satpal http://jsfiddle.net/LzFAr/44/

Comment: Is `RequestID` is used here for the sake of explaining or is it litterally that? If it is then this is wrong as IDs should be uniques!

Comment: @StealthRT, No you can't. [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) "The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document."

Comment: If you've respected the fact that IDs should be unique you wouldn't be in this dilemma in the first place. You could've just select them directly like `$("#id")`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir if you look at my code again you will see that I have unique identifiers but same element names *within* that unique id.

Comment: You don't have unique identifiers! There is two `id="RequestID"` and two `id="panHeading"`!

Comment: Unique ID > **<div class="cd-panel from-right" id="va">....</div>** and then for the next set of DIVs **<div class="cd-panel from-right" id="VDA">...</div>** Unique ID's are **va** and **VDA**.

Comment: IDs should be unique in the whole document not just inside an element!

Comment: Just call me a rebel without an unique id then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use, get rid of `>` it looks for immediate child and `RequestID` is not the child of `va` element.

```
$('#va #RequestID').val(responce["personData1"][0].RequestID)
```

Also note *Identifiers in HTML must be unique.* You can assign a class and then use it like

```
 <input name="RequestID" disabled="True" class="form-control input-sm RequestID"  style="width: 520px; max-width: 520px;" type="text">
```

and then

```
$('#va .RequestID').val(responce["personData1"][0].RequestID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#va [name='RequestID']").val(responce["personData1"][0].RequestID);
```

I think the problem is that you're trying to get an ID child of an ID, which should be unique, but you're using "RequestID" as ID on multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

**ID are designed to be a unique selector on the page. So the search would stop after the first match**
If you'd like to select multiple elements on the page based on a common pattern you should go for class selectors.

Now, to answer your question : 
HTML:

```
<input name="RequestID" disabled="True" class="some-input-class form-control input-sm" id="RequestID" style="width: 520px; max-width: 520px;" type="text">
```

and JS:

```
if (responce["personData1"][0].RequestID != 1) {
    $('#va .some-input-class').val(responce["personData1"][0].RequestID);
}
```

jsFiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bn32z64h/)

References:

[W3C docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

[Is selecting by class or id faster than selecting by some other attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460644/in-jquery-is-selecting-by-class-or-id-faster-than-selecting-by-some-other-attri)