# Check if a class `active` exist on element with jquery

Tags: jquery, class

Check if a class `active` exist on an `li` with a class `menu`

For example

```
<li class="menu active">something...</li>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if an element has a CSS class with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263232/determine-if-an-element-has-a-css-class-with-jquery)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I think you want to use hasClass()

```
$('li.menu').hasClass('active');
```

Answer (score 9):

You can retrieve all elements having the 'active' class using the following:

```
$('.active')
```

Checking wether or not there are any would, i belief, be with

```
if($('.active').length > 0)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$('li.menu.active')
```

is the simplest way. This will return all elements with both classes.

Or an already answered [jQuery hasClass() - check for more than one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214952/jquery-hasclass-check-for-more-than-one-class/2214962#2214962)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `hasClass` method, eg.

```
$('li.menu').hasClass('active') // true|false
```

Or if you want to select it in one go, you can use:

```
$('li.menu.active')
```

Answer (score 6):

**Pure JavaScript** answer:

```
document.querySelector('.menu').classList.contains('active');
```

Might help someone someday.

Answer (score 5):

```
    if($('selector').hasClass('active')){ }
```

i think this will check if the selector hasClass active ...

Comment: FYI: While your answer appears plausible, it has appeared in the 'low quality posts' queue after being flagged for deletion. I suspect this is because it is a code only answer without explanation.

Comment: i have added some explanation

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  changeColor = $(.active).css("color","any color");
  if($(".classname").hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).eq(changeColor);
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

use the hasClass jQuery method

Answer (score 0):

### If Condition to check, currently class active or not

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    if($('p:last').hasClass('active'){
       $('.active').removeClass();
    }else{
       $('.active').addClass();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

i wrote a helper method to help me go through all my selected elements and remove the active class.

```
    function removeClassFromElem(classSelect, classToRemove){
      $(classSelect).each(function(){
        var currElem=$(this);
        if(currElem.hasClass(classToRemove)){
          currElem.removeClass(classToRemove);
        }
      });
    }

    //usage
    removeClassFromElem('.someclass', 'active');
```