# More than 1 selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this selector:

```
if($('body').hasClass('page-modellen', 'page-modellen-detail')){
```

But this is not working. I want. When the page hass class page-modellen or page-modellen-detail than he must doing that code. How can i fix that?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if($('body').is('.page-modellen, .page-modellen-detail')){
    console.log('x')
}
```

Comment: you are looking for a div not for the whole page

Answer (score 2):

[**.hasClass(className)**](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) can't hold multiple className.

I used **`.is()`** selector for this.

```
if($('body').is('.page-modellen, .page-modellen-detail')){
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nmp99/4/)

Comment: Please share the reason for downvotes.  So that I can learn/rectify right?

Comment: `is()` can't handle multiple arguments.

Comment: @mplungjan, that's a multiple selector in a single argument, not multiple arguments.

Comment: @VisioN thanks, but I have a doubt, how this worked `$('body').is('.page-modellen', '.page-modellen-detail')`  What I understand it look for the first parameter and negalected the second one.  Please correct me if I meant wrong

Comment: @user, you're right, passing multiple arguments to `is()` is not supported, and only the first one will be taken into account. Passing a multiple selector in a single argument will work, on the other hand.

Comment: @user1671639 Yep, in your case `.is` took into consideration the first argument and skipped the rest. It gave you the correct result since the element indeed has `"page-modellen"` class.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `window.console && console.log($('body.page-modellen, body.page-modellen-detail').length);` // returns 1  from @mplungjan gave an insight.  Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @mplungjan VisioN is correct. 'Arguments' means functional arguments, i.e. `.is('.class1', '.class2')` vs. `.is('.class1, .class2')`. Read carefully [Frédéric's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360014/more-than-1-selector#comment28686152_19360049).

Comment: @mplungjan My first comment was referring to the very first revision of the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19360049/1, which had a problem with multiple arguments, as we discussed.

Answer (score 2):

check here

[jQuery OR Selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263975/jquery-or-selector)

Your code should be:

```
if($('body').is('.page-modellen, .page-modellen-detail')){
```

Comment: Are you sure, this is what the OP have already  didn't worked http://jsfiddle.net/Nmp99/1/

Comment: you are right, I copied and paste the wrong line - try now http://jsfiddle.net/Nmp99/2/

Comment: You missed `.` selector.  Your fiddle is wrong,  returns false.  Correct your code

Comment: sorry guys, looks like I have to close stackoverflow for today or try to really focus on something

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard about `||`? :)

```
if ($('body').hasClass('page-modellen') || $('body').hasClass('page-modellen-detail'))
```

Comment: Yea, about minute ago, while reading @ArunPJohny answer.

Answer (score 1):

So many answers, many ways to answer this.

Let me add one more that wasn't answered here yet:

```
if ($('body.page-modellen, body.page-modellen-detail').length > 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('body').hasClass('page-modellen')|| $('body').hasClass('page-modellen-detail')){
  // do stuff 

}
```

reference [JQuery .hasClass for multiple values in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559153/jquery-hasclass-for-multiple-values-in-an-if-statement)