# I want to remove class if two classes found in a div, with jQuery function I have tried but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".block").addClass("dock_on_load");

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var someElem = $("#block-region-side-post");
    if (someElem.is('.block, .hidden')) {
       $('.dock_on_load').removeClass('dock_on_load');
    }
});
```

I want to remove class dock_on_load if two classes found .block, .hidden and other hand if only block class found add dock_on_load but it is not working

Comment: you want to remove .dock_on_load from $someElem or need to remove other element with .dock_on_load ??

Comment: dont use '.' in hasClass() , just use hasClass('someClass')

Answer (score 0):

use below code . don't need to use before class '.' in [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).

```
if ($someElem.hasClass('block') && $someElem.hasClass('hidden')) {

       $('.dock_on_load').remove();  //if you want to remove element 

   // if you wan to remove class from $someElem use below code

      $someElem.removeClass('dock_on_load'); 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.removeClass();` instead of `.remove();`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Nishit's answer, you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var someElem = $("#block-region-side-post");
    if (someElem.is('.block, .hidden')) {
       $('.dock_on_load').removeClass('dock_on_load');
    }
});
```

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559177/2355043), this approach may be slower than using `hasClass`.

Comment: Note: just to be clear, if performance is at all a concern, go with `.hasClass`.