# Jquery check for multiple classes (All must be present) in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to check if an element has the classes I am finding ex:

```
<span class="foo bar me"></span>
```

I want to check if the `foo` and `me` class is present on that element so I used this:

```
$('body span').hasClass('me', 'foo')
```

this foo and me is stored in an array but this one didn't work:

```
var arrayName = ['me', 'foo'];
$('body span').hasClass(arrayName)
```

the classes I am finding is dynamic that's why it is stored in an array, how can pass the dynamic array like the this one `'me', 'foo'` to the hasClass function?

***Note:*** the array can have 2-4 values in it.

I had my work here: https://jsfiddle.net/pcbttntk/

Thanks in Advance.

***Update:*** `$('body span').hasClass('me', 'foo')` is not working, thanks to brett and Roko, it only checks the first class passed to it.

Comment: That's wrong: `.hasClass('me', 'foo')`.

Comment: possible duplicate. please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10559177/520544

Comment: Hi Jörn the case in this one is that the all class in the array must be present on that specific element, the answer on that question is just checking if one of the classes is present on the element, and the classes it check is not dynamic.

Comment: @Cedric yes you're right. i've removed my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having:

```
<span class="foo bar me"></span>
```

#### Has both `me` and `foo` classes:

```
$('span').is(".foo.me");
```

Using an **array of classes** you could use `.join()` to get the needed string selector `".foo.me"` like:

```
var classes = ['me', 'foo'];
$('span').is("."+ classes.join("."));
```

or simpler:

```
var classes = ['.me', '.foo']; // (Notice the `.`)
$('span').is(classes.join(""));
```

---

To recap, `.hasClass('me', 'foo')` is basically wrong cause `.hasClass()` accepts only one argument

Comment: hi roko, the `console.log( $('span').is(classes.join("")));` do it but the class must be in chronological order, the array in my example isn't and will not work in my case because the array is dynamic will not be always in chronological order, I don't know why but `console.log($('body span').hasClass('bar', 'me'));` works

Comment: @Cedric works cause `"bar"` is the only considered class and your element logically HAS that class.

Comment: but in my case I need `bar` and `me` to be in that class in which if `me` is not present it should throw `false`

Comment: @Cedric I gave you 2 possible variants , what's not clear? see this example: http://jsbin.com/xalotac/1/edit?html,js,console,output You're clearly interested in the `&&` variant (AKA: "must have all specified classes"). Seems you're sleep deprived :D

Comment: Hi roko, seems I am just confused on your answer, the `console.log( $('span').is("."+classes.join(".")) );` works not this one `console.log( $('span').is(classes.join("")) );` I only tries the second one which is the simpler one, didnt check the first, which is the one that works in my case. thanks Roko!

Comment: @Cedric you're welcome! (Read carefully, I've stated in the second example that it uses `['.me', '.foo']; // (Notice the `.`)` )

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.hasClass()` only accepts a single class, as a string (according to the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)).

To test for multiple, dynamic classes you can use `.is()`:

```
var class1 = 'me';
var class2 = 'foo';

arrayNames = [class1, class2];

console.log($('body span').is(arrayNames.map(function(className) {return '.'+ className;}).join(',')));
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/72evLvyp/2/).

Comment: Hi brett this one checks if any of the class is present on that element, I have to check if all of the classes if present on that specific element.

Comment: `.is()` function can't be used in my case because it has the condition `or` not `and` when checking if the classes is present on that element.

Comment: @Roko, the classes need to have a `.` prefixed.

Comment: How would I both prefix `.` and append a `,` using `join()`?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody have you seen my answer?