# Check if elements has class which is given in a list/array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add to specific elements of a list the class `.disabled`.
These elements can be found in an array or something like that - don't know what is recommended for this.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id=anything>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-deleted"></a> Text</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-bold"></a> Text</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-italic"></a> Text</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-table"></a> Text</li>
</ul>
```

This should become this:

```
<ul id=anything>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-deleted"></a> Text</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-bold disabled"></a> Text</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-italic"></a> Text</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-table disabled"></a> Text</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var arr = ['re-bold', 're-table'];
$('#anything a').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('anything of the array') ) { // Check if this element has a class, which is given in the array
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hasClass() - check for more than one class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214952/jquery-hasclass-check-for-more-than-one-class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a `.` to the array's elements, either manually or by using the `Array.prototype.map` method. and join the array's elements. Then `filter` method will filter the matching elements according to the created selector:

```
var arr = ['.re-bold', '.re-table'];
$('#anything a').filter(arr.join()).addClass('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
var arr = ['re-bold', 're-table'];
$('#anything a').each(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(arr[i])) $(this).addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j9L9kLvn/)**

Produces:

```
<ul id="anything">
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-deleted"></a> Text</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-bold disabled"></a> Text</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-italic"></a> Text</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="re-icon re-table disabled"></a> Text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the array, to check for each class:

```
var arr = ['re-bold', 're-table'];
$('#anything a').each(function() {
    var i = 0, 
        arrayLength = arr.length;
    for(; i < arrayLength; i++){
        if ( $(this).hasClass(arr[i]) ) {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e6mds7vz/1/