# Check if a div has all four classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically this is a filter for wordpress.

All posts are shown in one page and I have added category names as classes to the main div (.box) of a post where one div will have multiple classes.

There are  fours drop downs in the filter widget with all the categories listed as options.

I wanted to show only that div which has all the active category names as classes.

Following is the code. With the IF condition, how can I use idea of "AND"?

This code gives me an error.

```
$('#filter select').change(function()
    {
            var upper=$('#upper').val();
            var sole=$('#sole').val();
            var toe=$('#toe').val();
            var midsole=$('#midsole').val();

            $('.box').each(function()
            {

                if($(this).hasClass(upper) && hasClass(sole) && hasClass(toe) && hasClass(midsole))
                {
                    $(this).show();
                }
                else{
                    $(this).hide();
                }
    });

});
```

Comment: You have missed `$(this).` with `hasClass(sole)`

Comment: You may probably have to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214952/jquery-hasclass-check-for-more-than-one-class

Comment: @madalinivascu : those are not divs but select dropdowns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$.fn.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method like this with combined class selected:

```
$('#filter select').change(function () {
    var upper = $('#upper').val();
    var sole = $('#sole').val();
    var toe = $('#toe').val();
    var midsole = $('#midsole').val();

    var classes = '.' + [upper, sole, toe, midsole].join('.');
    $('.box').hide().filter(classes).show();
});
```

Basically, construction `'.' + [upper, sole, toe, midsole].join('.')` produces a string of four classes concatenated with `.` character: `.class1.class2.class3.class4`, which is a CSS selector for `.box` element having all 4 classes at the same time.

Comment: This is sick man! Worked right away. 
Just one more question. The first option of each dropdown list is "all" which I added manually. How do I make it work so that posts with one of the categories under that dropdown will show up if ALL is selected? Thanks a lot for the help dude.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `$(this)` to `hasClass`.

```
if($(this).hasClass(upper) && $(this).hasClass(sole) && $(this).hasClass(toe) && $(this).hasClass(midsole)) {
    // Yes this div has all four classes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ele=$(this);

if(ele.hasClass(upper) && ele.hasClass(sole) && ele.hasClass(toe) && ele.hasClass(midsole))
```

1. You have to give `$(this)` to all the `.hasClass` API in the if condition.
2. So instead of repeating it assign it to a variable and use it as above.

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot the object jquery selector `$(this)`.

```
    if ($(this).hasClass(upper) && $(this).hasClass(sole) && $(this).hasClass(toe) && $(this).hasClass(midsole)) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.hasClass("class1 class2 class3")` if you sure in order,
else

```
this.hasClass("class1) && this.hasClass("class2 ")
```

Answer (score 0):

A more beautiful way to do this:
$("#myId").is(".foo.bar")

Edit: this is also independent of the order of classes